# How do I play the online co-op campaign?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

My friend and I really enjoyed playing the co-op campaign together in Magic 2012.  However, we can't figure out how to play the co-op campaign in Magic 2013.  According to [Cooptimus](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/2565/pc/magic-the-gathering-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013.html), the game supports 2-player online coop.  So, **how do we play it?**

Answer (score 3):

The referred site says:

> Two players can team up to play a Two-Headed Giant match versus the AI, either locally or online.

Are you sure you read somewhere that you can play Co-Op **campaign**?

Comment: ...I guess I just assumed, because it would be **insanely retarded** for them to have co-op campaign in Magic 2012 and not include one in 2013..